# Good web design software and HTML editor

Tags: html, css, editor

I use dreamweaver and i'm trying to teach my friend HTML and CSS but he needs a program like dreamweaver thats free. Do you know any good web design programs for beginners?

Comment: This is quite off topic and has been answered multiple times here and on superuser.

Comment: Uh, Dreamweaver isn't really for teaching someone HTML and CSS at all.

Answer (score 15):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) on Windows

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) or [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) on Mac

Or, if you have a penchant for regex and infinite time to learn commands : [VIM](http://www.vim.org/)

Get in there and get dirty with the code and mash F5 on the browser (if you are on Windows or Command + R on Mac), best way to learn HTML and CSS. WYSIWYG editors are just a bad influence, because they don't teach you best practices.

Some tutorials from [html-dog](http://www.htmldog.com/) are where you want to start.

Comment: thats not even close to what i asked

Comment: @master565 you dont get the point? You **dont** use WYSIWYG editors to LEARN HTML and CSS, you **hand code** to learn the basics, bad habits learned from the start are the hardest to get rid of.

Comment: If you are recommending a Mac app (Coda), you shouldn't say F5 :)

Comment: @Myles Gray: Influence doesn't have a plural in this context.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning VIM. Just kidding ;)

Comment: +1 for NP++. It's where I started when learning.

Comment: +1 now that you stuck Vim in there :)

Comment: Wouldnt you know it, the one time I can get "Enlightened" I know the OP wont accept it :P

Answer (score 7):

You aren't happy with @Myles answer so let me elaborate.

You said you want to teach your friend HTML and CSS: well, **the best way to do that** is to get a text editor and start writing code. There might be a slightly steeper learning curve, as there always is when doing something that a piece of software would otherwise do for you using a GUI, but within a short while you'll actually save time not having to plough through the GUI to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

**Notepad++**, as far as your non-vim, non-eMacs text editors go, is a pretty good solution for Windows. **Textmate** would be a great alternative for Mac OS.

The answers so far are very reluctant to offer up WYSIWYG alternatives to Dreamweaver since the community at large is reluctant to utilise these tools, and with good reason. Back in the days when websites consisted of **table-based spaghetti**, a tool like Dreamweaver might well have come in handy. But now that the focus is on writing clean, semantic markup and reusable CSS, a WYSIWYG editor on autopilot isn't going to be up to the job.

*Another thing:* the Adobe suite of products are very good at what they do. Dreamweaver, as it goes, is the market leader. But **when Dreamweaver has shortcomings in itself, why would you want to resort to a poor alternative?**

Comment: Would +1 but all votes gone for the next 2 hours :(

Comment: @Myles Gray Then come back ;)

Comment: there is your + as promised :)

Answer (score 3):

A few tools for this:

- Coda, from Panic: http://panic.com/coda
- Emacs
- Vim
- [Butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/)

For the actual design, Photoshop and Pixelmator seem to be good.

And if you want such a horrible WYSIWYG, the only thing I can think of is Dreamweaver or Frontpage, but I've never worked with them and I never will do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/), its open source.

Checkout the screenshots first: http://kompozer.net/screenshots.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) by Sun Microsystems

Comment: @markus Good point. @Xcoder you should elaborate in the same way that others have pointed out the relative merits of text editors in relation to writing markup and styles. FWIW NetBeans is an IDE, so it has some extra stuff in there like code completion, testing, debugging, compiling and well, erm, everything. Make sure you've got about a terrabyte of DDR3 memory in your machine though or else it will kill it!

Comment: XXXcoder is a great programmer! I love you

Answer (score 0):

For just HTML/CSS I agree with Myles Gray. Go for a simple text editor instead of some IDE or WYSIWYG apps like Dreamweaver; you'll get used to the code a lot faster if you start out by typing it yourself.. even if it means spending a lot of time on that.

Once you know the syntax/code/etc inside out, move on to something like Aptana, NetBeans, Coda or another IDE of your preference.

Good luck.

Comment: im not trying to learn it myself im trying to teach someone it

Comment: Still, he'd have to get down and dirty with the code to take it all in and actually LEARN. The best way to do this is with a simple editor like Notepad++ or Textmate. Once he gets his html/css code down, he can move on to a IDE. You don't learn by using code-hinting.

Comment: I would rather attempt to write html in a dos prompt than use Dreamweaver

Comment: @Nick I'd rather write it in `cat` then use Dreamweaver

Comment: @master565, I suggest that you make him use Dreamweaver for 1 hour when he makes a mistake while you're teaching him. He will learn his lesson fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac, [Smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/) has a basic WYSIWYG, but I haven't tried to push it too far. You're always going to get browser rendering problems.